# How to make json encode with jsp from jdbc resultset?

Tags: java, mysql, json, jsp, jdbc

I want to build an application using jsp, but I have a trouble when I want to get result from query resultset database. I need output json format from query resultset. This is my code if using php:

```php
<?php 
  include "koneksi.php"; 
  $sql = "select * from siswa"; 
  $result = mysql_query($sql); 
  $json = array(); 
  if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
      $json['aaData'][]=$row; 
    } 
  } 
  echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to separate things. Converting something to json doesn't really have to do with getting data from a result set. To find out how to get data from a result set, read the JDBC api documentation and any fine tutorial on JDBC. For converting to JSON, select a library and read its documentation, then connect the dots.

Comment: Note that while it's possible to use JDBC directly in a jsp page, this is not recommended. You should consider creating a servlet (extend HttpServlet class) and have your code access your database (via JDBC) in either doGet or doPost method (or both).